# math classes to take for path

Tags: education

I have taken:
Calc 1, 2, & 3,
Introduction to Discrete Math,
and Introduction to Statistics.

The maths I learn I wish to be *most* applicable to programming (any kind of programming, game, physics, AI, etc ...)

Classes I get to choose from, bold ones are ones I have chosen

- Introduction to Proof,
- Foundations of Analysis,
- Foundations of Algebra,
- Intermediate Analysis I,
- Axiomatic Geometry,
- Ordinary Differential Equations,
- **Linear Algebra**,
- **Combinatorics**,
- Introduction to Abstract Algebra,
- **Probability and Statistics I**,
- Dynamical Systems,
- **Numerical Methods** (= numerical analysis? Do I have to take anything before this?)

Would these classes help the most? Would you recommend any other classes that are perhaps not on this list? A class in physics with calculus perhaps?

Also all I need is a short answer, yes or no, is the knowledge of any math applicable to programming?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question, yes, math is *very* applicable to programming.

**Linear** and **Combinatorics** are excellent choices.

It's a bummer that there isn't an **Intro to Number Theory** course on your list because that class could teach you a lot of tools that you could use a programmer to find elegant solutions to complicated problems. Also, the mindset that a number theory class would install in you would serve you well as a problem solver.

As for the classes from your list, I would recommend either **Intro to Abstract Algebra** or **Intro to Proofs**. It would do best to install that same problem-solving mindset that number theory would.

Comment: there is a 'Discrete Mathematics for Computing' but i figure it was the same as intro to discrete just a different name. and no theres no number theory only courses

Comment: @hit It probably is about the same. Depending on your situation (do you need these class for a degree?, etc) you might want to ask a professor for a book recommendation for either *number theory* or for more advanced discrete mathematics material. If you think there is a professor who would be willing, you could ask to do some independent study with them.